# Get ASU,RNC,UCID, and Power of Neighbor Mobile Transmitter Using Telephony manager in android

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I want to fetch this value for each transmitter provider using Telephony package Manager or any code else

1. ASU
2. RNC
3. UCID
4. POWER

I am already able to get **CID,LAC,RSSI** value using the below code but i can't get the above,

```
    List<NeighboringCellInfo> neighbors = telephonyManager .getNeighboringCellInfo();
     for (NeighboringCellInfo n : neighbors)
     {

                        cid_lst.add(n.getCid());
            lac_lst.add(n.getLac());
            psc_lst.add(n.getPsc());
            rssi_lst.add(n.getRssi());

      }
```

Please help me

Comment: did you find any way to find these values ?

Comment: I think this question would be better adressed in the more specific QA site Telecommunications proposed here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/104688/telecommunications
If you like the proposal, ask your question there and follow the proposal as well